# Оптимизация запроса и структуры БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных, статистика

Имеется таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stats` (
  `stats_id` bigint(21) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stats_server_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stats_time` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stats_players` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stats_map` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stats_server_status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stats_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`stats_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=29302216 ;

/* пару строк для понимания */
INSERT INTO `stats` (`stats_id`, `stats_server_id`, `stats_time`, `stats_players`, `stats_map`, `stats_server_status`, `stats_timestamp`) VALUES
(28117217, 9, 1463702411, 9, '$2000$', 1, '2016-05-20 03:00:13'),
(28122217, 9, 1463702530, 8, '$2000$', 1, '2016-05-20 03:02:11'),
(28127217, 9, 1463702649, 9, '$2000$', 1, '2016-05-20 03:04:10');
```

Все работало нормально пока таблица не начала заполнятся, в итоге мой запрос занимает очень много времни:

```
SELECT * FROM  `stats` WHERE  `stats_server_id` =  '9' AND  `stats_time` > 1463702400
```

(233 всего, запрос занял 5.4820 сек.)

Меня почемуто убеждают что timestamp будет работать быстрее, ну я добавил его и вот результат:

```
SELECT * FROM  `stats` WHERE  `stats_server_id` =  '9' AND  `stats_timestamp` > '2016-05-19 00:00:00'
```

(233 всего, запрос занял 5.5570 сек.)

Что меня удивляет, так это скорость работы этого запроса:

```
SELECT * FROM  `stats`
```

(29,277,215 всего, запрос занял 0.0005 сек.)

И что интересно если выбирать по `stats_server_id` то выходит довольно не плохо, но мне нужно же и выборка по времени:

```
SELECT * FROM  `stats` WHERE  `stats_server_id` =  '9'
```

(5,857 всего, запрос занял 0.0261 сек.)

Для теста сделал еще такие запросы, и понял что проблема есть хоть с `stats_timestamp` хоть `stats_time`

```
SELECT * FROM  `stats` WHERE  `stats_timestamp` >  '2016-05-19 00:00:00'
```

(1,395,000 всего, запрос занял 7.9079 сек.)

```
SELECT * FROM  `stats` WHERE  `stats_time` >1463702400
```

(1,155,000 всего, запрос занял 8.6857 сек.)

я конечно грешил на условие `>` но тесты с `stats_timestamp =`, `stats_time =` и `stats_server_id =` показали другое:

```
SELECT * FROM  `stats` WHERE  `stats_timestamp` =  '2016-05-20 11:18:11'
```

(119 всего, запрос занял 7.6739 сек.)

```
SELECT * FROM  `stats` WHERE  `stats_time` =1463702411
```

(5,000 всего, запрос занял 6.2635 сек.)

```
SELECT * FROM  `stats` WHERE  `stats_server_id` =9
```

(5,875 всего, запрос занял 0.0262 сек.)
Почему так происходит если `stats_time` и `stats_server_id` поле имеет значение `int(10) DEFAULT NULL`?
Как можно оптимизировать запрос, или структуру БД для шустрой работы?

Comment: Индексы проставьте по нужным столбцам. Естественно, что оно медленно работать будет, если надо каждую запись прочитать и проанализировать.

Comment: @Etki но посмотрите на последние два запроса, там нет индексов. почему же такая разница?

Comment: Скорее всего там какие-то оптимизации из-за низкой cardinality. Я не могу сказать почему где-то получается быстро, но без индексов вы вряд ли сможете делать быстрые выборки по большому количеству данных.

Comment: @wwwplaton Раз у вас поиск по server_id подходит очень быстро, значит по нему есть индекс. он мог быть создан автоматически если вы делали фореджен например. для поиска по вашему условию должен быть составной индекс по обоим полям (stats_server_id, stats_timestamp). Может конечно поможет просто по stats_timestamp, но зависит от интрвала времени и количества разных server_id. Так же для анализа производительности время запроса второстепенно. Необходимо выполнять и внимательно изучать explain для данных запросов

Comment: @Etki я добавил индексы к `stats_server_id` и `stats_time` результат меня просто убил, первый в списке запрос теперь работает _(282 всего, запрос занял 0.0284 сек.)_ ударьте меня, и ткните носом в мануал что б больше такие вопросы не задавал :)

Comment: @Mike спасибо, но по поводу explain я вообще не понял что там можно найти. если в ответ почти везде NULL выдавал. Хотя после добавления индексво он заговорил иначе: ` Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [select_type] => SIMPLE
    [table] => stats
    [type] => ref
    [possible_keys] => stats_time,stats_server_id
    [key] => stats_server_id
    [key_len] => 5
    [ref] => const
    [rows] => 4628
    [Extra] => Using where; Using filesort
)`

Comment: @wwwplaton Ну когда поле key пустое - значит индекс не используется вообще, т.е. для поиска нужен полный перебор таблицы. В колонке rows вы можете видеть сколько записей он предполагает просмотреть для поиска результата. У вас 4628 - вполне приемлемое количество, явно не 29кк. Это собственно и есть так называемая селективность индекса. обратите внимание, что одновременно может использоваться только один индекс. хотя не понятно что у вас там за filesort. Он обычно при order by бывает

Comment: @Mike то есть то что я сделал для двух полей индексы это плохо? к примеру в другой таблице выборка идет по нескольким полям, и я думаю для них для всех сделать индексы. Или я не прав? По поводу  filesort вы правы, просто массив вывести было проще с проекта. Там вот такой запрос был: `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM stats WHERE stats_server_id = '9' and stats_time > '1463653011' ORDER BY stats_id DESC , stats_time ASC`

Comment: @wwwplaton Индексы для двух полей одновременно не работают. Можно сделать один составной индекс из нескольких полей, причем те поля которые обычно проверяются по полному равенству, вроде server_id должны быть первыми, а те что на больше-меньше после них. Любой индекс замедляет вставку новых записей, поэтому городить много индексов так же не стоит. Надо оценивать как часто ищут по этим полям.

Comment: @wwwplaton  И разумеется надо понимать селективность. Если бы у вас было бы всего 2 server_id на 29млн записей то server_id=1 выбрал бы примерно 15млн - такой индекс никому не нужен, отобрать 15млн по индексу дольше чем перебором таблицы и БД просто не станет его использовать. Индекс полезен когда на одно значение ключа приходится совсем малая часть данных. Поэтому один индекс по двум полям (server_id, time) хороший, ключ из этих двух полей скорее всего вообще уникален. И даже при необходимости может использоваться для поиска по server без указания времени

Comment: @Mike, говорят, в MySQL последних версий уже добавили возможность использовать множественные индексы http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-merge-optimization.html (мопед не мой, если что)

Comment: @Etki Даже в оракле, который merge index поддерживает уже много лет оптимизатор реально этим редко пользуется. Поэтому если можно сделать один индекс, лучше сделать один. Хотя конечно составной по (server, time) не позволит искать по времени без указания сервера, что возможно плохо